# Sort the elements in Python List by date in it

Tags: python, list, pyspark

I have list with all file names as below and i need to sort them and process in ascending order. code i used is working fine in python3 commandline but not working pyspark. Code i tried is

```
from datetime import datetime
def sorted_paths(paths):
    paths.sort(key = lambda path: datetime.strptime(path.split('_')[2], '%Y%m%d'))
    return paths
```

Gives an error:

```
Error: time data daily doesn't match the format '%Y%m%d'
```

Input List is as below:

```
file_d_20190101_htp.csv
file_d_20180401_html.csv
file_d_20200701_ksh.csv
file_d_20190301_htp.csv
```

Required output

```
file_d_20180401_html.csv
file_d_20190101_htp.csv
file_d_20190301_htp.csv
file_d_20200701_ksh.csv
```

Comment: It seems like you're running it with the wrong paths. `print(paths)` to make sure you're getting the right files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just do this, convenient and quick:

```
paths = ['file_d_20180401_html.csv',
 'file_d_20190301_htp.csv',
 'file_d_20180401_html.csv',
 'file_d_20200701_ksh.csv',
 'file_d_20190101_htp.csv',
]
paths.sort()  # in place sort
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use python embedded function `sorted` to resolve this:

```
import datetime

arr = ['file_d_20190101_htp.csv',
'file_d_20180401_html.csv',
'file_d_20200701_ksh.csv',
'file_d_20190301_htp.csv']


print(sorted(arr, key=lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x.split("_")[2], '%Y%m%d')))
```

Answer (score 0):

One way using `dateutil.parser`:

```
import dateutil.parser as dparser

f = lambda x: dparser.parse(x, fuzzy=True)
sorted(paths, key=f)
```

Output:

```
['file_d_20180401_html.csv',
 'file_d_20190101_htp.csv',
 'file_d_20190301_htp.csv',
 'file_d_20200701_ksh.csv']
```